# Windmills in Space

Tags: design-alternative, power, cold-gas-thrusters

What if we put a windmill like we use now in space like on moon or a space station so its attached to the surface and since we have no wind we use air tanks in the blades to rotate, everytime it slows down due to friction and electricity generation we fire the air tanks again to make it spin would that work/be more efficient than the windmills on earth?
(lets ignore how to refuel the air tanks and stuff like that)

Comment: I think you should reword your answer so it sounds less like you are proposing a perpetual motion machine.

Comment: This would be horribly inefficient.  Compressed air can be used as a form of energy storage, but then the best way to extract power is with a bespoke turbine. For peak efficiency you would have something like a steam power plant’s turbine, many many gentle stages.

Comment: in what way could it possibly be more efficient to provide your own wind instead of using wind that already exists?

Comment: Unsure what this question means, but one option would be a solar-sail turbine, operating horizontally in a carousel structure. In the low gravity of the moon, this could provide constant power whilst in the sun, and maintain some momentum if an initial spin was performed mechanically.

Comment: Also you would make more electricity by using an air-powered turbine, and pressurized air.

Comment: This is one for the record books.

Comment: Your specific question is interesting from a physics standpoint, *"would that work/be more efficient than the windmills on earth? (lets ignore how to refuel the air tanks and stuff like that)"*. In other words would a windmill work differently in a vacuum and either 1/6 or zero-g. This would be difficult to test on Earth. You could place a windmill in a vacuum chamber along with a can of compressed air, however once the air starts blowing the pressure will rise in the chamber which will affect the test. Perhaps a small windmill in one of NASA's large vacuum chambers would be a good test.

Comment: Those aren't windmills, they're giants!

Comment: Are we talking about like a wind turbine, or a wind powered water pump (like the famous Dutch windmills or a farm windmill), or a wind powered flour mill? I mean it's horrifically inefficient either way, but I'm curious what kind of windmill you have in mind.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym presumably this is to power the tanning beds.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Space Exploration, and appears to stem from a misunderstanding of basic physics.

Comment: @RoryAlsop, I disagree on both counts. Space power generation is perfectly on topic. Also the asker is basically suggesting a novel (yet feasible) form of power extraction from compressed air. This thread reveals this communities lack of reading comprehension and an unwillingness to engage with hypothetical systems.

Comment: @AMcKelvy - please read our [help] and [ask] pages. Questions on hypothetical systems are generally off topic here, and explicitly called out as such in those pages. And while gas turbines may be on topic, the "would that be more efficient than windmills on earth" demonstrates misunderstandings that are possibly insurmountable without entirely changing the question.

Answer (score 2):

I like this idea, it’s very steampunk astronautic.

We use windmills on Earth because they can capture the Sun’s energy in the form of air currents. The Sun replenishes these continuously, so it is a renewable source of energy, and a windmill doesn’t require any infrastructure once it’s installed.

In space, the problem is that there are much better alternatives than shipping wind in tanks.

There is an awful lot of embedded energy in your cold-gas-thruster windmill, for very very little actual electricity provided:

- The tanks are heavy and have to be sent to space, which takes an ***unfathomable*** amount of energy.
- The windmill and its frame is likewise very heavy

To make things worse, windmills have lots of moving pieces, which means they will be very tricky to fix when they break, as you’ll be fixing them *in space*.

For the same mass budget, we already have much more efficient means of delivering energy to a lunar base/space station:

- Batteries aren’t as dense as we’d like, yet they still win over compressed air
- Photovoltaic solar panels (works great ~50% of the time!) are very reliable and can be used for *decades* without refueling/recharging anything
- Fuel cells (extract electrical energy from chemical energy) pack a lot of chemical energy in a small mass budget
- Nuclear reactors are incredibly energy-dense, but have that pesky problem of being radioactive, so they need a lot of shielding.

But if you do need a lightish spinny thing (for the vibe), you *could* [use rocket fuel and LOX to run an engine](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8749/759), and have that turn a generator… that could be quite powerful.

Comment: Shuttle APUs used a little "rocket engine" to turn a turbine...kind of like your last paragraph.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes! I also added a link in that paragraph to a previous question I (barely) remembered.